# Getting @@identity or Scope_identity() inside default value mapped to a scalar function

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with `ID` as identity column, and `Code` as a `varchar` column. `Code`'s default value is set to a scalar function `X`.

Inside that scalar function `X`, getting the `scope_identity()` or `@@identity` returns null. Is there a way to get the inserted identity without using insert trigger?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you considered using an Output clause in your Insert instead?

Comment: And when you insert multiple rows, what do you expect to happen? This smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it also suggests a normalization problem (since we normalize to avoid duplication).

Comment: Neither `scope_identity` or `@@IDENTITY` will have a value in the middle of an `INSERT`. I agree with @Smor, sounds like an XY problem; or perhaps `Code` should be a computed column.

Answer (score 0):

You could just skip the ID and IDENTITY altogether and generate the `code` as the primary key.  EG

```
--drop table if exists t
--drop sequence t_seq
--drop function t_key_gen 
go
create sequence t_seq start with 1000 increment by 1

go
create or alter function t_key_gen(@i int)
returns char(10)
as
begin
   return concat('AB',right(concat('0000000000',@i),8));
end

go

create table t(code char(10) primary key default dbo.t_key_gen(next value for t_seq), a int)

go

insert into t(a) values (1),(2),(3)

select * from t
```